# Listing the results of an absentee list

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to produce a query that will  generate a list of absent students whenever a my code is typed.  The problem I am running into is that the output list is displaying none of the names of the students that were in class. My goal is to only list students that are over 30 days according to their most recent recorded date of attendance. Students that are not over 30 days will not be shown at all. It seems pretty simple enough however I'm running into a block. Is there a Syntax or two that I am missing?

```
SELECT  trim(concat(name.fname,' ' ,name.mname,' ',name.lname)) as student, name.noiid as stuID, sum(meeting.meefoiid) as NO_CLASS, squadlt.ltfname as Squad
FROM name  
LEFT JOIN meeting  ON name.foiid = meeting.meefoiid
LEFT JOIN squadlt  ON name.squadlt = squadlt.ltid
WHERE  meeting.meefoiid IS NULL 
AND MEEDATE >= '2014-09-12'
AND name.city = 'RICHMOND'
GROUP BY student
ORDER BY name.squadlt, student;
```

Comment: If you like, consider following this simple two-step course of action: 1. If you have not already done so, provide proper DDLs (and/or an sqlfiddle) so that we can more easily replicate the problem. 2. If you have not already done so, provide a desired result set that corresponds with the information provided in step 1.

Comment: You are misusing the MySQL `GROUP BY` extension. Please read this: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/group-by-extensions.html . Because of this extension, lots of underspecified aggregate operations work and give unpredictable results. This makes it hard to read your query and figure out what you're trying to do.